# Wanna ask about breaking the loop in a defined function?

Tags: loops, if-statement, break

i have a defined function called x(), and I call this function inside the while loop in another defined function y(). Inside the x(), I have an if statement in it. I don't know how to code (if something is true for the if-statement in the x(), then break the while loop in y()?

Comment: What programming language are you using? [edit] your question and add it to tags.

Comment: Specify programming language. You can return boolean value from function x() and check that condition in y() function using if condition if x()==true. and use break statement to exit from while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def x():
    return True
def y():
    while True:
        if x():
            break
    print("Out of Loop")
y()
```

I assume function x is returning true. `if x():` this check if function return true than it will break the loop in function y(). You can return bool value in x() function and check that bool value in y() function to break the loop

[image]